# How to calculate reduction of inductance eddy currents in ferromagnetic core?

Tags: inductance, coil, high-frequency, loss

Suppose you have a LC circuit. Now at high frequency the core loss of the inductor meaning hysteresis and eddy current loss will increase. When this happens the frequency increases while the inductance will decrease.

Now how can one calculate the decrease of inductance due to the eddy currents?

Comment: Again, it's got nothing to do with losses.

Comment: Do you still need this question answering given the answer I provided yesterday?

Comment: @Andyaka No the answer from yesterday explained everything perfectly fine. Should I delete this one then?

Comment: I don't think Tony's answer is relevant but, in fairness you should ask him before deleting and maybe refer him to your other question that I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Inductors are rated at the -10% L threshold due to core losses.

This must be done in conjunction with a ferrite supplier and core design for shape and material depending on your AC and DC requirements.

https://www.inductor.com shows many suppliers below to choose from.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with -10% threshold?

Comment: current @ 90% of max L

Comment: Is it okay for you if I delete this question since I already have an answer explaining these phenomena really well here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545106/effect-of-core-losses-on-inductance-in-high-frequency-lc-circuit

Comment: Sure you can delete it . Computing the mathematical result requires the application of Lenz's Law https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrw-i5Ku0mI, This can also occur in non magnetic materials like ALuminum and copper